# Frequency of occurrence of dry and wet months rasterbrick R

Tags: r, time-series, frequency, raster

I have a rasterbrick, `a` made of monthly time series from 1950-2014 (see below). The task I am trying to accomplish on a is to calculate at each grid point:

`negative/positive number of  dry/wet months per total months of  dry/wet events*100`,

where

dry has values in the range `−1.49 to −1.00` and wet values are in the range `1.49 to 1.00`.

The resulting output is a single `rasterLayer` with dry=negative percentages and wet= positive percentages such that I can map a raster with blue for wet and red for dry.

**Sample data can be found [HERE](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnVl_zW00EHegxAprS4s7PDaYQVr)**

```
dd=spei03_df
dd[1:2]<-dd[2:1]#swap lat and lon
a=rasterFromXYZ(dd)
dates=seq(as.Date("1950-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), by="month")
a=setZ(a,dates)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that should work for you. It does not generate positive and negative percentages, but rather the percentage of one of your values. The way percentages work, you'll still be able to map out what you want.

Note: rather than using your dataset, I created a sample data with the same value range. The values will be more or less random sampled (I included a bias for warmer* to get a tendency for one color), so don't expect a pretty pattern.

```
library(raster)

## create sample data

#values
dry <- seq(-1,-1.49,by=-0.01)
wet <- dry * -1

#raster brick

r <- lapply(seq_len(length(1950:2014)*12),function(x){

  r <- raster()
  r[] <- sample(c(wet,dry),ncell(r),T,c(rep(0.3,50),rep(0.7,50)))
  r
})

r <- do.call(brick,r)

names(r) <- seq(as.Date("1950-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), by="month")

#output

> r
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 180, 360, 64800, 780  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 
data source : /tmp/Rtmp3BTUH1/raster/r_tmp_2017-08-09_120141_2859_73743.grd 
names       : X1950.01.01, X1950.02.01, X1950.03.01, X1950.04.01, X1950.05.01, X1950.06.01, X1950.07.01, X1950.08.01, X1950.09.01, X1950.10.01, X1950.11.01, X1950.12.01, X1951.01.01, X1951.02.01, X1951.03.01, ... 
min values  :       -1.49,       -1.49,       -1.49,       -1.49,       -1.49,       -1.49,       -1.49,       -1.49,       -1.49,       -1.49,       -1.49,       -1.49,       -1.49,       -1.49,       -1.49, ... 
max values  :        1.49,        1.49,        1.49,        1.49,        1.49,        1.49,        1.49,        1.49,        1.49,        1.49,        1.49,        1.49,        1.49,        1.49,        1.49, ... 
  -1.49,   -1.49,    -1.49,    -1.49,    -1.49,    -1.49,    -1.49,    -1.49, ... 
max values  :    1.49,    1.49,    1.49,    1.49,    1.49,    1.49,    1.49,    1.49,    1.49,     1.49,     1.49,     1.49,     1.49,     1.49,     1.49, ...
```

And now to calculate the frequencies:

```
rfreq <- calc(r,fun = function(x){(sum(x > 0) / nlayers(r))*100})
```

Like this, every pixel will have a value between 0 and 100, indicating a range from all months dry to all months wet, with the equilibrium at 50. So you can easily map this with red and blue. If you still want the percentages, you can just add a legend with the respective labels:

```
library(rasterVis)

my.at <- c(0,30,50,70,100)

myColorkey <- list(at=my.at,
                   space = 'bottom',
                   labels=list(
                     labels=c('extreme dry','dry','normal','wet','extreme wet'), ## labels
                     at=c(15,40,50,60,85) ## where to print labels
                   ))

levelplot(rfreq, at=my.at,
          colorkey=myColorkey,scales=list(draw=FALSE),margin=FALSE,
          par.settings=RdBuTheme(),
          main = 'Precipitation 1950 - 2014',
          xlab=NULL, ylab=NULL)
```

[image]

HTH

*

> Climate change is real

Comment: this seems to get me on the right track. However, I get `values      : 22.30769, 36.53846  (min, max)` after running `rfreq <- calc(r,fun = function(x){(sum(x > 0) / nlayers(r))*100})`. This means that we have 22 to 36% wet? what about dry? I did `rfreq <- calc(r,fun = function(x){(sum(x < 0) / nlayers(r))*100})` and got `values      : 63.46154, 77.69231  (min, max)`. I need a single rasterLayer for both wet and dry. Just wondering how you got values between 0 and 100%? Thanks.

Comment: Basically, a value of 50 means equal distribution. Depending on what variable you choose (`> 0` for wet or `< 0` for dry), a value less than 50 will indicate the complement. So in your first example you choose `x > 0`, a value of 22 will mean this pixel is more dry, specifically 78% (1-22) of the months have a dry value.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the clarification @Val